# What Share permissions am i forgetting?

Tags: document-library, permissions, security, document

Hi I've setup a 2013 Sharepoint site on my companies 365 org and none of my users can see the documents in the folder. The users are signed in properly and i've shared the folders with NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users as well as Everyone except external users. What as I'm forgetting advice welcome. They can see folders but not documents.

Comment: check the view, is it all item view? is their any filter on view...from ribbon click on modify the view and see if their is any filter on it....also try to create a new view and then test

Comment: I'm currently only using the all item view with no filters. I had out sharepoint admin check the settings and directory and he can't see any documents as well.

Comment: Try to upload a new document? Then test it...how many documents u have?

Comment: just tried to upload a document to a directory in the library no one can see it.

Comment: Weired, any unique permission? Try to access it from different browser...

Comment: Also try with a account having site collection admin rights...

Comment: are there checkedout documents ?

Answer (score -1):

I forgot to check-in the documents. Thanks kesava